# Python: How to have a for loop print a randomly generated item in a list every time?

Tags: python, for-loop, random

EDIT: Random "for loop" output fixed. Now am receiving "list index out of range error".

I am meant to be making a grading program that is based on randomly generated letter grades (A-F). The program asks for the amount of assignments and prints the assignment number with the letter grade. It should also find the average grade of the randomly generated grade. The output should look something like this:

```
Assignment 1 grade is an F
Assignment 2 grade is a C
Assignment 3 ...
The average is a ...
```

I have a list set up to randomly generate the letter grade. I am having trouble setting code to find the average of the letter grades. Also, my loop does not spit out a new letter grade every time as it should. Here is some of my code:

```
numberlist = []
numberlist.append("A")
numberlist.append("B")
numberlist.append("C")
numberlist.append("D")
numberlist.append("F")

count = 1
for i in range(total):
    numberindex = random.randint(0, 5)
    print("The grade for assignment", count, \
          "is a {}".format(numberlist[numberindex]))
    count = count + 1
```

It currently prints:

```
Assignment 1 grade is an F
Assignment 2 grade is an F
Assignment 3 grade is an F...
```

Comment: You're seeting `numberindex` before the loop, so it's value is the same/unchanged each time it loops through . . .

Comment: You're only generating one random number. Get a new random value inside the loop.

Comment: Minor: your "numberlist" contains nothing but string letters..

Comment: You have already accepted an answer, but you are editing your question?

Comment: Am now receiving list index error for some of the larger input statements. Did not occur when testing with smaller numerical values, so yes I edited the question.

Comment: randint is inclusive: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make a random choice every time the loop iterates to a new element.

```
numberlist = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"]

for i in range(total):
    choice = random.choice(numberlist)
    print('The grade for assignment {i} is a {mark}'.format(i=i+1, mark=choice))
```

Comment: If you're choosing a letter directly, you shouldn't try to index into numberlist with it.

Comment: I dont get exactly what you mean with "index into numberlist". `random.choice` selects one element from a iterable. Doesn't matter what type of elements are inside the iterable.

Comment: What do you think your `numberlist[choice]` is doing?

Comment: Where do you see numberlist[choice] ?

Comment: This is getting silly.  `format(i=i+1, mark=numberlist[choice]))`

Comment: Okay, I did not notice that the print statement was the issue here. Edited. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the random number generation inside of the loop:

```
for i in range(total):
    numberindex = random.randint(0, 5) ####here!
    print("The grade for assignment", count, \
      "is a {}".format(numberlist[numberindex]))
    count = count + 1
```